# Amazon EC2 SFTP Connection From Filezilla Issue

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

I've launched a new amazon ec2 instance and tried to connect both from *Putty* and from FileZilla.

The connection from *Putty* was successful, while the connection from Filezilla, which uses the same credentials (host,username=ec2-user,empty password, .ppk file) fails with the following error:

```
**Error**:  Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
**Error**:  Could not connect to server
```

I'd like to know how to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same type of issue while ago with FileZilla. Then, I started to use Bitvise SSH Client - http://www.bitvise.com/ssh-client